# What's best practice to ensure JavaScript objects are set and not undefined when handling multiple leveled objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a js developer and work in an environment where we do API calls and get some data returned. The structure of the data returned is HIGHLY inconsistent so therefor we can't assume anything about the data returned.

Picture the following scenario:

```
$.ajax({
    success: function(data){
        // Now I want to access a property 4 levels in
        var length = data.results.users.length;
        doSomeStuffWithLength(length);
    }
})
```

What's the correct way to ensure `data.results.users.length` is not undefined? Because of the inconsistencies from the API, each level of the returned object could be broken/undefined. Do I really have to do the following:

```
if (data && data.results && data.results.users && data.results.users.length){
    var length = data.results.users.length;
    doSomeStuffWithLength(length);
}
```

Aren't there more elegant solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create helper function like this.
Expect object with structure like this :

```
var someObj = {
  some: {
    other: {
      third: 'bingo',
      qwe: 'test'
    }
  }
};
```

Would be great to have something like

```
getPropByPath(someObj, 'some.other.qwe');
```

So the implementation of `getPropByPath` may looks like following:

```
function getPropByPath(obj, path){
  var parts = path.split('.'),
      root = obj;

  for(var i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
    if(root[parts[i]] !== 'undefined') {
      root = root[parts[i]]
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return root;
}
```

Comment: For your solution - in case of OPs situation he/she needs to do: `if (getPropByPath(data, 'results.users') && getPropByPath(data, 'results.users').length)`? Looks a bit redundant to me.

Comment: @KooiInc hm, not sure got your point correct. my helper just returns property value is exists or false. In described case in may be much easier `var value = getPropByPath(data, 'results.users') || [] // or any other data type u need as default val, lng = value.length`

Comment: @Evgeniy Shouldn't it be i = 1 in the for loop? Otherwise you're starting on the main object..

Comment: @Weblurk, no, we should start from 0. If we start from 1 the first property will be checked in main object will be `other` but it doesent exist. The idea is to get `root` object, check if first property exist then dig in and move `root` to this nested property or return false

Answer (score 1):

If at all levels there may be something undefined, you should check all levels, something like:

```
var length = data && 
             data.results && 
             data.results.users && 
             data.results.users.length || 0;
```

You can also use some helper function. Here's one:

```
function getPropValue ( path, defaultIfNotExisting ) {
  defaultIfNotExisting = defaultIfNotExisting || 0;
  path = path.split('.'), test = this;
  while (path.length) {
    test = test[path.shift()];
    if (!test) {
      return defaultIfNotExisting;
    }
  }
  return test;
}
// usage in your case:
if ( getPropValue.call(data, 'results.users', []).length) { /* do stuff */}
```

Comment: what reason to provide empty array as param to helper ? Plus its not secure to check `length` - what about if function return Number ?

Comment: @Evgeniy: that's because the check concerns checking the `length` property of the returned value. If `length` is 0, the expression evaluates to `fals(e/y)`

Comment: so if getPropValue retursn int 4, you are trying to check int length and receive `undefined` as result in spite of the fact function returned value you handle it as property doesent exist

Comment: Yep, in *this case* that'll be true. Read the comment in the answer: `//usage *in your case*`. Creating/using helper methods doesn't change the fact that a programmer needs to think about how to use them.